# Cast Dictionary<Key, Value> to IReadOnlyDictionary<Key, IValue>?

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface, casting

We can easily do this :

```
List<Value> list;
IReadOnlyList<IValue> List => list;
```

But how can we do the same with IReadOnlyDictionary?

```
Dictionary<Key, Value> dict;
IReadOnlyDictionary<Key, IValue> Dict => dic; //impossible
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, however at the cost of *allocations* and *rehashing* you can project it:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IValue> Dict 
   => dict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => (IValue)x.Value);
```

Though you may need to rethink your problem.

Comment: Yes, i think the best option is to add a function like : IValue Get(Key key) => dict[key]

Answer (score 3):

This is because `IReadOnlyList` is covariant:

```cs
public interface IReadOnlyList<out T> {...}
```

whereas `IReadOnlyDictionary` isn't:

```cs
public interface IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue> {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that `IReadOnlyDictionary` is invariant begs the question why it has to be that way. The reason is that it is *impossible* to add any variance to that interface, from just taking a look at how it is defined:

```
public interface IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    bool ContainsKey(TKey key);
    bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value);

    TValue this[TKey key] { get; }
    IEnumerable<TKey> Keys { get; }
    IEnumerable<TValue> Values { get; }
}
```

You can't make either `TKey` contravariant (`in`) or `TValue` covariant (`out`). It is obvious that `IReadOnlyDictionary<object, …>` cannot be an `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, …>`, because `IEnumerable<object> Keys` cannot be `IEnumerable<string>`.

As for `out TValue`, that could work conceptually, but there are two parts that prevent it from happening: `IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, since you cannot cast `KeyValuePair<…, string>` to `KeyValuePair<…, object>` because non-interface/delegate types cannot have variance at all, and `out TValue value`. Ironically, `out TValue` method parameter cannot work with `out TValue` type parameter, since under the hood it is still `ref`. Both of these blockers can be removed in theory, but it is something .NET itself has to improve.

In my opinion, rather than to copy the values to a new detached dictionary, it is better to make a projection that still accesses the original dictionary. You can make that with zero costs using a `struct`:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;

public struct ProjectedValueBaseReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TDerivedValue, TBaseValue> : IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TBaseValue> where TDerivedValue : TBaseValue
{
    readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TDerivedValue> inner;

    public ProjectedValueBaseReadOnlyDictionary(IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TDerivedValue> inner)
    {
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public TBaseValue this[TKey key] => inner[key];

    public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys => inner.Keys;

    public IEnumerable<TBaseValue> Values => (inner.Values as IEnumerable<TBaseValue>) ?? inner.Values.Cast<TBaseValue>();

    public int Count => inner.Count;

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return inner.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TBaseValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach(var pair in inner)
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TBaseValue>(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out TBaseValue value)
    {
        var result = inner.TryGetValue(key, out var value2);
        value = value2;
        return result;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

If you then write methods like `M<TDict>(TDict d) where TDict : IReadOnlyDictionary<Key, IValue>`, passing in `ProjectedValueBaseReadOnlyDictionary` should lead to optimized inlined code that simply accesses the `inner` dictionary.